# Ensure 2 Users can't modify same object at the same time

Tags: android, ios, database, parse-platform, schema

I am using parse.com for the backend of my new iOS/android game. The way users join games is they select the type of lobby they want to join, for example:

Apple

Orange

Lemon

The user would select one of the lobby types, and the app will query for lobbies of that type with LESS THAN 4 users in it (Array of users). If it finds one, it will add the user to it, if not I will create a new lobby with the user as the first person in the lobby.

My question is how do I ensure that, however unlikely, when 2 users both search for the "Apple" lobby, and an object with 3 users is returned, they both don't get added into the lobby? I need to ensure that the game stays at 4 players or less, and that only one of them gets added to the lobby, and the next one gets added to a new lobby. Is there a way to check if another user is currently modifying an object? What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: You shouldn't allow the user to modify the object.  The user should submit  request to join and they get an answer back yes/no from the server.  You can use cloud code to do this; but you still need to deal with the concurrency - see here for some ideas - https://parse.com/questions/locking and https://parse.com/questions/concurrency-management-in-parse

Comment: @Paulw11 sorry, maybe I wasn't being clear. I am using cloud code to add suers to the lobby object, but I still need to deal with the concurrency issue.

Comment: You can check first if the lobby is already full before the user enters it

Comment: Expanding on the ideas I linked to and NaviRamyle suggestion, you should implement a function, say, *joinLobby* that uses `incrementKey` to return your 'position' in the lobby. If it returns <5 you are OK.  if it returns 5 or more then you need to try another lobby.

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm not sure I quite understand. Do I need to save the object as soon as I increment? Or does it update the object without saving so the lobby is closed automatically?

Comment: The `incrementKey` operation is atomic when you save. So your app would call the cloud code function `joinLobby` - the cloud code function would use `incrementKey` followed by save to increment the "lobbyMembers" counter.  If the value of "lobbyMembers" after the increment is >4 then you can return false or something to let the app know that the lobby was already full when it tried to join.  If the value after the increment is <= 4 then you can return true (I just checked the docs and it is `increment` not `incrementKey` in Javascript

Comment: See the `_joinMatchAttempt` method in https://github.com/Mattieuga/ParseGameManager/blob/master/parse/cloud/game_matching.js

Comment: @Paulw11 Doesn't this still leave a possibility for the cloud code function to be called for the same lobby at the same time? I know this is a very small possibility but am I understanding this wrong?

Comment: If you relied upon "read, add one, write" in your own code then you have a race condition because both players could read, both add one and both write" but the `increment` operation is atomic inside Parse's code.  When you save the object with an increment operation then internally Parse performs the read, add one, write without any possibility of another task performing a read until the write is complete, so if the starting value is 3 and two players call increment then one will get 4 and the other will get 5

Comment: @Paulw11 Ah okay I understand now. Thank you for explaining that. I will implement that in my code. If you add this as an answer I will gladly accept it.